# sparklines with real time data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

How can I create a sparkline with real time data coming from event listener in javascript ?

I tried couple of resources, but none of them gives me a clear understanding of how can I continuously send the data points to sparkline to plot them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery.sparkline there is no way to incrementally add points to the graph. Instead you have to redraw the entire graph with each update.